# Drawing a filled-in arc using TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw the area formed by an arc of a circle (specifially 3/4 of a circle, that is `0 <= \theta <= 3\pi/2`) with a radius of 4 using TikZ. I also need the interior of that arc filled in. here is what I have thus far, but 'too' much is filled in, and that may be a result of the manner I have use to draw the arc:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [->] (-5.0,0)--(5.0,0);
\draw [->] (0,-5.0)--(0,5.0);
\filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=blue] (4,0) arc (-0.05:275:4.0cm);
    \foreach \x in {-4,4}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
    \foreach \y in {-4,4}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I add some complements and some explanations to the fine answer from Peter.

Firstly, you can solve your problem with the pgfmanual *Filling and Drawing* in **A Picture for Karl’s Students**.

Some explanations about the code given by T.Tantau. When you need to fill an area, like Peter wrote, you need to give a closed path but it's possible to give any path ( see  the examples below). If the path is not closed, then Tikz closes the path automatically with `-- (origin of the path)`. In your code the most important part is `(0,0) --`.

`-- cycle` is important for **drawing** the path because in some case you need to join correctly the curves I put two red circles around the problem if you draw with or without `cycle`. You can see in the third picture that it's not necessary to use `cycle` with `fill`. In the first and second example, I show two different results with and without  `cycle` .

Some examples with some variants from the example given in Karl's tutorial :

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
  \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black]
    (90:3mm) arc (90:0:3mm) arc (180:90:3mm) ;
\end{tikzpicture} 

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
  \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black]
    (90:3mm) arc (90:0:3mm) arc (180:90:3mm) -- (0:6mm) -- (0,0) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}  

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
  \fill[fill=green!20!white]
    (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm);
\end{tikzpicture}  
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
  \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black]
    (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture} 
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=6]
  \filldraw[fill=green!20!white, draw=green!50!black]
    (0,0) -- (3mm,0mm) arc (0:30:3mm) -- (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

In your case :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[->] (-5.0,0) -- (5.0,0) node[right] {$x$} coordinate(x axis);
\draw[->] (0,-5.0) -- (0,5.0) node[above] {$y$} coordinate(y axis);

\filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=blue] (0,0) -- (4,0) arc (0:270:4.0cm) -- cycle;

\foreach \x in {-4,4}
\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
\foreach \y in {-4,4}
\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$};
\node at ( 45:2){\Huge \textbf{R}} ;
\node at ( 45:5){\Huge or  \textbf{R}} ; 
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks to both Peter and Altermundus for your help and solutions. Just one more question-how can I add the x and y labels for each coordinate axis -- I am going to try and find the line I need from the example code in the manual, but the question is in case I cannot. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @MichaelDykes I updated my answer

Answer (score 16):

You simply need to start and end at the origin:

```
(0,0) -- (4,0) arc (0:270:4.0cm) -- cycle
```

to obtain the region you desire:

[image]

### Note:

- Not sure why you had `-0.05:275` degrees in your MWE. I have corrected that to be `0:270` to correspond to `0:3\pi/2`.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \draw [->] (-5.0,0)--(5.0,0);
    \draw [->] (0,-5.0)--(0,5.0);
    
    \filldraw[fill opacity=0.5,fill=blue] (0,0) -- (4,0) arc (0:270:4.0cm) -- cycle;

    \foreach \x in {-4,4} {\draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};}
    \foreach \y in {-4,4} {\draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east ] {$\y$};}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```